# Permission to my application data

Tags: android

I'm new to android and having a headache trying to do this scenario:

I'm creating a backup of my database, which is exists in a path like this:

```
String dbPath = "data/data/" + c.getPackageName() + "/databases/" + DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
```

I'm copying current database file to another in same directory with a custom extension, something like this:

```
String backupName = "data/data/" + a.getBaseContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/MyDB_" + MyTools.GenerateDateNow() + ".mydb";
```

then i use a recycler view and an adapter to loop through files inside the folder, and get my custom created files

i also have a button inside the recycler view, which will restore the created backup.

everything up till now is alright and works fine.

what i want to do next is the problem:

i need to share these backups with other people ( if user decides to ), and to do that, i have used Intents to send a user selected backup file to all apps which work with files ( gmail, whatsapp, ...):

```
 holder.btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.setType("file/*");

                Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);

                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share With...");
                chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                v.getContext().startActivity(chooserIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

the selected file will be picked and sent to the chooserIntent, but it seems like the chooserIntent has no permission to access it, i guess it's something simple that I'm missing

Comment: Do you get an exception? Can you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: Move the File to some other folders such as data folder in sdcard or internal storage. then send the data over email. This is what I do in my last project.